# How can I extract the number and the immediate two letters after it using Regex?

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I have strings similar to

'Coke blahblah 2000ml, (20) blahblah'
'Coke blahblah 2000ML, (30) blahblah'
'Coke blahblah 2L, (20) blahblah'.

I need to extract the volumes, units of volume, the number in brackets.

Volumes are 2000,2000,2. Units of volumes are ml,ML,L. Number in brackets is 20,30,20

How to do that using Regex?

Answer (score 0):

Something like the below would do it

```
regex = r"'(\w+?)\s.+?(\d+(ml|l)),\s\((\d+?)\).+?'"

test_str = "'Coke blahblah 2000ml, (20) blahblah' 'Coke blahblah 2000ML, (30) blahblah' 'Coke blahblah 2L, (20) blahblah'"

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE)
```

You can test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/RWywxz/1), that'll give you a breakdown of what it's doing. Although you didn't provide real data so you might have to adapt it somewhat.